# Creating Oracle Custom View, passing parameters through URL, numeric parameters work, alpha do not

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, url, parameter-passing

I will start by saying that I am new to this.I am trying to create a custom view in Oracle. I am passing parameters from my html file to xml. Everything works fine if the parameter is numeric. If the parameter is alpha, I get no data returned. I have hardcoded the selection data into the SQL and I get data returned so I know the data exists.

In HTML file:

```
<SCRIPT TYPE="text/javascript">
    function resize()
    {
        window.moveTo(0,100);
        top.window.resizeTo(960, 500);
    }

    function processSubmit()
    {


             var idssn = document.form1.idssn.value;

    if(idssn != "")
    {
        var mainURL = "";
        var viewName = "PTIN";

        mainURL = "Web-ASPX/" + viewName + ".aspx" + "?ID1=" +  idssn;
    window.open(mainURL,"newpage",'width=960,height=700,left=0,top=100,screenX=0,screenY=100,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes');
```

In XML file:

```
<control controlID="PTIN" type="WEBGRID">
    <hiddenFields>          
        <fieldName>NUM</fieldName>
    </hiddenFields>

    <SQL>
        <query> 

            SELECT  
                p.ssn as "SSN",
                p.ptin as "PTIN",
                p.ptin_issuance_date as "PTIN_ISSUANCE_DATE",
                p.ptin_status as "PTIN_STATUS",
                p.last_name as "LAST_NAME"
            FROM its_preparer_tin p
            where p.ssn = trim(' ? ')                                                         

         </query>

        <condition></condition>
        <parameterContext index="1">
                <parameterName>ID1</parameterName>
        </parameterContext>


    </SQL>
```

Comment: `trim(' ? ')` ?!? This should be parsed as a literal ` ? ` -- not a placeholder. It is rather surprising this works even in some cases. Or do I missed something here ?

Comment: It does work for numeric parameters. I couldn't tell you why. As I said, this is all new to me. What would I use to parse the URL?

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, I suspect the `?` is a placeholder for a bind variable.

Comment: @Marianne, I believe it is possible to have an "SSN" with alphabetical characters. I would try adding the `UPPER()` function to your query, e.g., `WHERE p.ssn = UPPER( TRIM(' ? ') )`

Comment: UPPER does not change the result. Thanks, though

Comment: Would it be possible for you to indicate (a) the data you're passing in the URL and (b) a sample of the data you expect to be returned?

Comment: The passed URL is as follows:                                                         Web-ASPX/PTIN.aspx?ID1=P0054430X

Comment: I would expect to get a row back containing that PTIN number P0054430X

Comment: But you're checking `SSN` instead of `PTIN` ... if you want to check both you can use `IN`: `WHERE UPPER(TRIM(' ? ')) IN (p.ssn, p.ptin)`

Comment: I have changed the query to select data by PTIN. The query works when selecting by SSN or zip code or any other numeric value. The problem is that I cannot select by a field that is alphanumeric. It always returns 'no data to display'. So in my example, if the ssn was alpha, then the query would not work.